# Did Anno animate any cuts in Neon Genesis Evangelion himself?

Tags: anime-production, neon-genesis-evangelion, hideaki-anno

Before Anno directed Evangelion, he was known for his animation in Studio Ghibli series, specifically Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind, as well as his work on mechanical and plane sakuga sequences for various other studios. He's definitely a skilled animator. That leads me to the question of whether he actually animated any of the iconic scenes from Eva. Or was he too preoccupied as the director of the series to do any of the key frames himself?